# What does 'vector-valued' mean?

Tags: dataset, terminology, gaussian-mixture-distribution, linear-algebra

What is the difference of a feature vector and a 'vector-valued observation' as described [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2005/09/gunawardana05__hidden_condit_random_field_phone_class.pdf)?

The term 'vector-valued' is used in the following context:

> "Most state-of-the-art [Automatic Speech Recognition] systems use vector valued observations, which are modeled with Gaussian mixture emission densities."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that something is vector-valued is simply another way of saying that something is a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), e.g. in [regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

$$ \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon} $$

$\mathbf{y}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ are all vectors and $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix, so $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \dots, \beta_k)$ is vector-valued parameter.